# AnimatedPictures in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I want a UIImageView to animate with different types of pictures. This is my following code :

```
@IBOutlet var AnimatedPicture: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    AnimatedPicture.animationImages = [

        UIImage(named: "name1.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "name2.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "name3.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "name4.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "name5.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "name6.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "name7.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "name8.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "name9.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "name10.png")!



    ]

    AnimatedPicture.animationDuration = 3
    AnimatedPicture.startAnimating()
    AnimatedPicture.animationRepeatCount = 0
}
```

The problem with this is, my images don't even show up. It's empty straight up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code, I couldn't figure out what was wrong with that other code.

```
//Animated Picture

@IBOutlet var AnimatedPicture: UIImageView!

let images = [

    UIImage(named: "name1.png")!,

    UIImage(named: "name2.png")!,

    UIImage(named: "name3.png")!,

    UIImage(named: "name4.png")!]


var index = 0
let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0.25
let switchingInterval: NSTimeInterval = 2

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    AnimatedPicture.image = images[index++]
    animateAnimatedPicture()
}

//Animated Picture

func animateAnimatedPicture() {
    CATransaction.begin()

    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(self.switchingInterval * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.animateAnimatedPicture()
        }
    }

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade
    /*
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    */
    AnimatedPicture.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    AnimatedPicture.image = images[index]

    CATransaction.commit()

    index = index < images.count - 1 ? index + 1 : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the same issue you had before (check that each image exists/can be loaded).

Comment: I checked that each image exists, are the same size, same images as before. It should work.

Comment: Ok, it seems like it should work, but it doesn't. Time to debug it. Do your files use different upper/lower case lettering in their names by any chance?

Comment: Nope! I checked that so many times. I have NO CLUE on why it won't work.